# how to extract the id from a string of specified pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex

The string is like this:

```
"grade_value[]=2&grade_value[]=3&grade_value[]=4&grade_value[]=5"
```

how could i transform it to `"grade_value in (2,3,4,5)"`

Comment: Where do you get the string from? Maybe you can just use `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are constructing where clause for mysql query.

```
parse_str($string, $output);
$values=implode(",",$output['grade_value']);
$str="grade_value in (".$values.")";
```

If that is not what you wanted please explain.

Comment: The string is from the url path

Comment: could i use the regular expression to parse and transform it?

Comment: @david: Pass the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead of `$string` in the `parse_str` function

Comment: @david: Are you trying to construct mysql query?  There is no need of regex. the parse_str function what for

Comment: OK. I've look up the parse_str function. I will try this way.Thank you!

Comment: @David: Why don't you just use `$_GET['grade_value']`? It already gives you an array of the values. No need to parse the query string manually.